# meta property og (The Open Graph protocol) not working

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I'm developing a new website in PHP. `meta property= og` is not working for me. This is my code

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="Website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.google.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.google.com/images/logo.png" />
```

Is there anything wrong in code? Or do I need to update anything on muserver settings?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing) and paste the URL of your site into it. This way you can refresh the scraping information by pressing the `Scrape Again` button and check if everything is being parsed correctly.